# Does Chilkat use local ports when communicate with imap via ssh?

Tags: php, sockets, chilkat

I use Chilkat component with PHP multithreaded application.

```
$this->tunnel = new CkSocket();
```

// Here is connecting to ssh

```
$this->imap->UseSshTunnel($this->tunnel)
```

And this is how I use ssh to communicate with imap via ssh.

On the server I also have apache2 running. And the problem is if I open more threads - apache doesn't handle requests. I think maybe Chilkat uses 80 port and then there is conflict ?

But I tried to check busy ports with ubuntu commands and I did not see that chilkat opened ports. Does chilkat do it ? What may be the problem ? Or can I set to chilkat the ports which must not be used ?

This question may touch not only exactly Chilkat component, but sockets generally

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here's the full example:   https://www.example-code.com/phpExt/imap_useSshTunnel.asp

In the example, Chilkat is not listening at any port.  In other words, Chilkat is not acting as the server-side of any connection.  The 1st step in the example above is to establish a connection to an SSH server.  The 2nd step is to have the IMAP client (Chilkat) use the existing SSH connection to establish the connection with the IMAP server.  Instead of connecting directly (IMAP client to IMAP server) you are establishing the connection through a logical channel on an existing SSH connection.  In other words, the IMAP protocol is tunneled through the SSH protocol.  In other words, data sent from Chilkat to the IMAP server first travels through the SSH tunnel, then at the SSH server, the data completes its journey to the IMAP server over a regular TLS or non-TLS connection.  (If a TLS connection is desired, then the TLS protocol itself is being tunneled through the SSH connection.)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I understand important info that in our case Chilkat is not a server and no port is listening when we connect to ssh. But local port should be opened when connect to ssh. Because such connection should be performed like: client_ip:client_port   <-->  remote_ip:remote_port , is it right ?